# Remove special apostrophe in R

Tags: r, text-mining, apostrophe

I am doing some text mining and I would like to remove the apostrophe " from my text (delete it). I tried to use gsub as follow but it does not work

```
text <- "\"branch"

removeSpecialChars <- function(x){
     result <- gsub('"',x)
     return(result)
}

without <- removeSpecialChars(text)
```

The desired Output would be branch and not "branch. Thanks for your help

EDIT to go further (i am trying to clean a text).

The Input is a list conatining a lot of different string. For example

```
Input <- list(c("e","b", "stackoverflow", "\"branch"))

cleanCorpus <- function(corpus){
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation,preserve_intra_word_dashes = TRUE)

  removeSpecialChars <- function(x){
    result <- gsub('"', "",x)
    return(result)
  }
  corpus.tmp <- removeSpecialChars(corpus.tmp)

  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, stripWhitespace)
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, content_transformer(tolower))
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
  return(corpus.tmp)
}
result <- cleanCorpus(Input)
```

Comment: I get `gsub('"', "", text)#
[1] "branch"`

Comment: May be the string you pasted here is not the one you have.  In your `gsub` call, there is no replacement.

Comment: @akrun thanks for your help however, i still have an error message no applicable method for 'tm_map' applied to an object of class "character". Do you know why? thanks

Comment: @akrun I add some codes, i try to build a function to clean text but it does not work, do you have any idea?

Comment: What is `corpus.tmp`?

Comment: sorry for this misspecification. it's some text read by the package tm from a pdf.

Comment: without a reproducible example, it is difficult to comment

Comment: Youre right sorry, since i am using internal data at my firm I try to create an Input which may help you to understand what I want. I would like the Input without any "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to use the `replacement`

```
gsub('"', "", text)
#[1] "branch"
```

#### data

```
text <- "\"branch"
```

Answer (score 1):

`result <- gsub("\"",text)` will work for you. You need to override that " by using .